# Do video serving servers have short names?

Tags: video, naming-conventions, camera

So there are video servers like Skype how do we call it? ()

So there are video servers like Red 5 how do we call it? (I suggest VOD but its protocol specific type - rtp rtsmp etc)

So there are video servers like servers for enterprice conferencing how do we call that? (like when they bring to you server for 20 gran and camera for 10 more and when you say you need another to communicate they say 30 more)

I am actually triing to write some project resume and I need to make short lables like o

> ur project differs from such ....
>   servers

And I actually need to compare my product to all of them but I do not know how to call each of them in a one  word?

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

- Skype servers do not really handle video traffic--the video goes from Peer-to-Peer.  Skype, SIP, etc are ***"presence servers"***.
- ***"Streaming server"*** seems to be the generic catch all for server software like red5, FMS, Wowza, etc.
- I would use the term ***"conferencing server"*** to describe things like BigBlueButton (which is kinda like what you have stated